# Compiling C programm with -std=c17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic error

Tags: c, gcc, compilation

Im very much new to C, used to Java and Python.

In one of my excercises I have to make sure that my program compiles correctly with the command:

```
gcc -std=c17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic file file.c
```

Unfortunately for me I get these errors:

```
/usr/bin/ld: file: stdout: invalid version 2 (max 0)
/usr/bin/ld: file: error adding symbols: bad value
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

My problem is that i have only very little ideas what the meaning of these errors could be (and also the added. My code is working perfectly fine. Here is the code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>

void child_A_proc()
{
  while (1) {
    fprintf(stdout, "%s", "A");
    fflush(stdout);
  }
}

void child_C_proc()
{
  while (1) {
    fprintf(stdout, "%s", "C");
    fflush(stdout);
  }
}

void parent_proc()
{
  while (1) {
    fprintf(stdout, "%s", "B");
    fflush(stdout);
  }
}

int main(void)
{
  int child_A;
  int child_C;

  child_A = fork();                 /* neuen Prozess starten                    */
  if (child_A == 0){                /* Bin ich der erste Kindprozess?           */
    child_A_proc();                 /* ... dann child-Funktion ausfuehren       */
  }else{
    child_C = fork();               /* neuen Prozess starten */
    if (child_C ==0){               /* Bin ich der zweite Kindprozess?          */
        child_C_proc();             /* ... dann child-Funktion ausfuehren       */
    }else{
        parent_proc();              /* ... sonst parent-Funktion ausfuehren     */
    }
  }
  return 0;
}
```

I tried to find some explanation in the internet but I couldn't replicate the solutions I found to my code. Well at least it didn't help me to understand the problem.

Comment: Try `gcc -std=c17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic file.c -o file` instead. The C code looks more or less fine to me, at least it compiles and links here.

Comment: That is: `-o file` on *nix and `-o file.exe` on Windows (Mingw etc).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Each non-option filename you give gets compiled as a C file or linked into the binary, depending on its type. (Not sure how the type is determined – I would guess from the file extension.)

On the command line you gave, there is `file` and `file.c`. Probably you meant for `file` to be the output filename, which should be preceded with `-o`:

```
gcc -std=c17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -o file file.c
                                     ^^
```

Answer (score 2):

You forgot the `-o` flag.
So the proper command should be `gcc  -std=c17 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic file.c -o file`.
At least on  my machine the code compiles.